# Display Picasa captions

Tags: jquery, html, photo-gallery, picasa

Just in case any one has tried this in the past.

I am using the Pimax plugin for displaying picasa photos on my webpage, it works great but I would like to display the captions as well.

Is this possible?

If not any help on where to start writing the function would be appreciated, can see nothing in the developer docs anywhere.

Comment: Okay, where exactly do you want the captions to appear, instead of the name of the image ?
Also you can try the [Pimax 2.0](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/03/pimax-20-embed-google-plus-picasa-album.html) version which is more user-friendly and responsive :)

Comment: @Patrick Yes, that would be ideal. Thanks, I will have a look at version 2.0

Comment: Just an update - Pimax 3.0 is already in progress and has an option to display captions instead of image name. Hope this solves your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo having Image captions in Pimax 3.0 -
http://buildwithcards.com/pimax_demo/pimax_live_edit.html

So by using the below option you can turn on Captions for images -

```
$("#pimax").pimax({
//other options
displayImageCaption:true
});
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know when version 3.0 will be released? Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Pimax 3.0 is already out on the [CodeHandling blog](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/04/pimax-30-complete-solution-for.html)